# useReducer hook isn't working, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I've used useReducer hook in react. al of my code seems right but it isn't working. Here goes my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';
import reducer from '../reducers/filter_reducer';
import { useProductsContext } from './products_context';
import { LOAD_PRODUCTS } from '../actions';

const FilterContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  filtered_products: [],
};
const FilterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { listOfProducts } = useProductsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_PRODUCTS, payload: listOfProducts });
  }, [listOfProducts]);

  return (
    <FilterContext.Provider value={{ ...state }}>
      {children}
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFilterContext = () => {
  return useContext(FilterContext);
};

export default FilterProvider;
```

and there goes my reducer function :

```
import { LOAD_PRODUCTS } from '../actions';

const filter_reducer = ({ state, action }) => {
  if (action.type === LOAD_PRODUCTS) {
    return { ...state, filtered_products: action.payload };
  }
};
```

export default filter_reducer;

It seems my code is right but after running this code it shows this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Can someone see where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
const filter_reducer = ( state, action ) => {
  if (action.type === LOAD_PRODUCTS) {
    return { ...state, filtered_products: action.payload };
  }
};
```